# XGBoost error - Unknown objective function reg:squarederror

Tags: python-3.x, regression, xgboost

I am training a xgboost model for regression task and I passed the following parameters -

```
params = {'eta':0.4, 'max_depth':5, 'colsample_bytree':0.6, 'objective':'reg:squarederror'}
num_round = 10
xgb_model = xgboost.train(params, dtrain_x, num_round)
```

In the training phase I get the following error-

> XGBoostError: b'[18:03:23] C:\Users\xgboost\src\objective\objective.cc:23: Unknown objective function reg:squarederror'

While in the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters), it is clearly a valid objective function. Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

**INFO-** I am using python 3.7.3 on windows and xgboost version is 0.82

Comment: Did you try to upgrade xgboost (pip install --upgrade xgboost) and scipy (pip install --upgrade scipy)? It worked for me today. I had the same issue

Comment: @LumberJack I just upgraded xgboost to version 0.90, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```py
xgb_model = xgboost.train(**params, dtrain_x, num_round)
```

This would work for all versions. It is the way to pass `**kwargs` as a dictionary.

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: This doesn't work in any version, since python doesn't allow keyword arguments before positional arguments.